# ValidationPipes doesnt work with Body specific type

Tags: typescript, pipe, nestjs, class-validator

I have simple question. I'm trying to apply a `ValidationPipe` to one of my endpoint which is POST This endpoint have simple responsibility - add an invoice, but before that I would like to validate body.

So I did that:

**invoice.dto.ts**

```
import { ContractorDto } from './contractor.dto';
import { IncomeDto } from './income.dto';
import { ExpensesDto } from './expenses.dto';
import {
    IdValidator,
    PositionValidator,
    DateOfEventValidator,
    DescriptionValidator,
    RegistryValidator,
    ContractorValidator,
    IncomeValidator,
    ExpensesValidator,
} from '../helpers/invoiceValidation.decorator';

export class InvoiceDto {
    @IdValidator() id: string;
    @PositionValidator() position: number;
    @DateOfEventValidator() dateOfEvent: string;
    @RegistryValidator() registry: string;
    @DescriptionValidator() description: string;
    @ContractorValidator() contractor: ContractorDto;
    @IncomeValidator() income: IncomeDto;
    @ExpensesValidator() expenses: ExpensesDto;
}
```

**invoices.controller.ts**

```
type XYZ = Omit<InvoiceDto, 'id'>;

@Post('/add')
addInvoice(
    @Res() res: Response,
    @Body(
        new ValidationPipe({
            transform: true,
            disableErrorMessages: false,
            always: true,
            stopAtFirstError: true,
            validateCustomDecorators: true,
            skipMissingProperties: false,
        })
    )
    body: XYZ, // here is a problem, when I'm using InvoiceDto - validation works, but when i try to use Omit it doesnt work
) {
    // I dont neet to validate ID field because I will generate it on backend
    const invoice = this.invoicesService.addInvoice(body);
    return res.json(invoice);
}
```

**invoiceValidation.decorator.ts**

```
export function IdValidator() {
    return applyDecorators(
        IsDefined({ message: 'ID of an inovice is required!' }),
        IsString({ message: 'ID must be a string!' }),
        Length(21, 21, { message: 'ID is not valid!' }),
    );
}

export function PositionValidator() {
    return applyDecorators(
        IsDefined({ message: 'Position of invoice is required!' }),
        IsNotEmpty(),
        IsInt({ message: 'Position of invoice must be a number' }),
        Min(1, { message: 'Position of invoice must be greater than 0' }),
    );
}

export function DateOfEventValidator() {
    return applyDecorators(
        IsDefined({ message: 'Date of invoice event is required!' }),
        IsOnlyDate(),
    );
}

  // I've just add a couple of validators
```

[GIST backup here](https://gist.github.com/Chester97/38edc3c613a3d0e1157b44e23b2833dd)

I think the problem is when i try to use `Omit<SCHEMA, OMIT_VALUE>` on body type, then i feels like my validator ignore my 'omit type for body' and pass all data.
I will be grateful for any help or advice

Comment: please read this https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#mapped-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `Omit<T>` generic, it won't work due to the fact that Typescript can't reflect generic types. You can make use of [`@nestjs/mapperd-types`](https://github.com/nestjs/mapped-types)'s `OmitType()` mixin to make a new class for you.

```js
export class OmitSchema extends OmitType(SchemaClass, ['fields', 'to', 'emit'] as const) {}
```

Comment: Nice! Thank You, I have already did this.
But still don't get that why it doesnt work with TypeScript Omit?
What does it mean - "ts cant reflect generic types"?

Comment: Nest uses what's called Reflection to get information about the route that is being handled. The parameter types of the route, the guards that should be run, pipes, etc. Generics are general types that take in an extra type argument (or more), such as `Omit<T, string>`. As `Omit` first of all isn't a class, typescript has trouble reflecting that, and even though it uses a generic class type for the first argument, Typescript can't reflect that information, so Nest can't make use of it. This is why Nest created the `@nestjs/mapped-types` to deal with situations like this